# How to run exe on remote PC using psexec

Tags: command-prompt, psexec

There is an exe (D:\TestFile.exe) in remote pc(SYSDES208). When run, it just creates a text file with some text. It works fine when run manually.
I'm trying to execute this from another PC this way, in command prompt.

```
D:\PsTools>cmdkey.exe /add:SYSDES208 /user:admin /pass:admin123
//Message - CMDKEY: Credential added successfully

D:\PsTools>psexec \\SYSDES208 D:\TestFile.exe
//Message - D:\TestFile.exe exited on SYSDES208 with error code 0.
```

There is no error and also no text file created.

The credentials passed in the command are of the remote PC's.

**UPDATE:**
Thought of using a batch file instead, to run the exe. So, I created a batch file with this code and placed it in the remote pc (D:\Test.bat):

```
start /d "D:\" TestFile.exe
```

Here are the commands run from the local PC:

```
D:\PsTools>cmdkey.exe /add:SYSDES208 /user:admin /pass:admin123
//Message - CMDKEY: Credential added successfully

D:\PsTools>psexec \\SYSDES208 D:\Test.bat
//Message - c:\windows\system32>start /d "D:\" TestFile.exe
            D:\Test.bat exited on SYSDES208 with error code 0
```

As seen in the message, the batch file is executed but the exe is not. What am i missing here

Answer (score 1):

My network admins would use Powershell for this. Not sure if you are restricted to only CMD.

invoke-command -computername SYSDES208 -scriptblock { D:\TestFile.exe }

If you are using a domain account or have the exact same account on the remote machine you shouldn't need to enter credentials as powershell will use the cred of the local user.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add credential as well to run that exe.(Pass the credential in PSEXEC command) Make sure that your account also has the write and modify permission at the location at which file is being generated

Comment: the credentials passed in first command are of the remote pc. When I do the same for second command , it says `Logon failure unknown username or bad password`

Comment: Just make sure your account has permission to write and modify files at that folder.

Comment: I modified TestFile.exe. It just opens a notepad now. But even that isn't happening. Does this require rights too. I'm not sure how to check that.